# What are the requirements to be installed in Android SDK for Cordova 7.0.1

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

Cordova requirements gives the following output:

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed

Android SDK: installed true

**Android target: not installed 
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1** Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more

Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle

Error: Some of requirements check failed

The output of ionic info is:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
Node  : v6.11.3
npm   : 3.10.10 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

I have Android studio installed, have installed the Build tools for Android API 26 and 25 , And android SDk for API 26 and 25 also.

Working on Android studio properly... Have tried the help available , but unable to resolve the issue....

Comment: Hi All, I got the solution and details are provided in the answer below

Comment: Summary: Latest version of Cordova 7.0.1 is not supporting the idk 9 , which may be due to its version name or other compatibility issue........ If you have latest version of Cordova i.e. Cordova 7.0.1 , you should stick to the last version of jdk 8 until the solution comes for Cordova

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had jdk 9 on my Mac

got the following output on running java -version

java version "9"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

but on running ionic cordova build android
the output was

```
 Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova

[18:30:48]  build dev started ... 
[18:30:48]  clean started ... 
[18:30:48]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[18:30:48]  copy started ... 
[18:30:48]  transpile started ... 
[18:30:52]  transpile finished in 3.55 s 
[18:30:52]  preprocess started ... 
[18:30:52]  deeplinks started ... 
[18:30:52]  deeplinks finished in 11 ms 
[18:30:52]  preprocess finished in 12 ms 
[18:30:52]  webpack started ... 
[18:30:52]  copy finished in 3.80 s 
[18:31:01]  webpack finished in 9.22 s 
[18:31:01]  sass started ... 
[18:31:03]  sass finished in 1.60 s 
[18:31:03]  postprocess started ... 
[18:31:03]  removed unused font files 
[18:31:03]  postprocess finished in 14 ms 
[18:31:03]  lint started ... 
[18:31:03]  build dev finished in 14.60 s 
> ionic cordova prepare android
> cordova prepare android

> cordova build android
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):


        ANDROID_HOME=/Users/behgals/Library/Android/sdk
        JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
        Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

**After searching on for hours -- finally decided to remove the idk 9 and switch to older version**

to remove the idk9 the following command is used

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/
```

and installed the idk8 last version

after installing everything works fine and the running of the command
    Cordova requirements :-$

```
cordova requirements
```

Requirements check results for android:

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-26,android-25

Gradle: installed /Applications/Android 
Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle
```

Comment: Summary: Latest version of Cordova 7.0.1 is not supporting the idk 9 , which may be due to its version name or other compatibility issue........ If you have latest version of Cordova i.e. Cordova 7.0.1 , you should stick to the last version of jdk 8 until the solution comes for Cordova

Comment: This solution applies to the same problem with Cordova 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Same for the latest Cordova 8.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

To me my java version was 11 and  it needs the version 8, so I changed the default version in linux with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

then set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables on ~/.bashrc (ubuntu):

```
#JAVA HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```